# Haskell: Equality constraint in instance

Tags: haskell

I was reading through the announcement of [ClassyPrelude](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/07/classy-prelude) and got to here:

```
instance (b ~ c, CanFilterFunc b a) => CanFilter (b -> c) a where
    filter = filterFunc
```

The writer then mentioned that this would not work:

```
instance (CanFilterFunc b a) => CanFilter (c -> c) a where
    filter = filterFunc
```

Which makes sense to me, as `c` is completely unrelated to the constraint on the left.

However, what isn't mentioned in the article and what I don't understand is why this wouldn't work:

```
instance (CanFilterFunc b a) => CanFilter (b -> b) a where
    filter = filterFunc
```

Could someone explain why this is different to the first mentioned definition? Perhaps a worked example of GHC type inference would be helpful?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Michael already gives a good explanation in his blog article, but I'll try to illustrate it with a (contrived, but relatively small) example.

We need the following extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}
```

Let's define a class that is simpler than `CanFilter`, with just one parameter. I'm defining two copies of the class, because I want to demonstrate the difference in behaviour between the two instances:

```
class Twice1 f where
  twice1 :: f -> f

class Twice2 f where
  twice2 :: f -> f
```

Now, let's define an instance for each class. For `Twice1`, we fix the type variables to be the same directly, and for `Twice2`, we allow them to be different, but add an equality constraint.

```
instance Twice1 (a -> a) where
  twice1 f = f . f

instance (a ~ b) => Twice2 (a -> b) where
  twice2 f = f . f
```

In order to show the difference, let us define another overloaded function like this:

```
class Example a where
  transform :: Int -> a

instance Example Int where
  transform n = n + 1

instance Example Char where
  transform _ = 'x'
```

Now we are at a point where we can see a difference. Once we define

```
apply1 x = twice1 transform x
apply2 x = twice2 transform x
```

and ask GHC for the inferred types, we get that

```
apply1 :: (Example a, Twice1 (Int -> a)) => Int -> a
apply2 :: Int -> Int
```

Why is that? Well, the instance for `Twice1` only fires when source and target type of the function are the same. For `transform` and the given context, we don't know that. GHC will only apply an instance once the right hand side matches, so we are left with the unresolved context. If we try to say `apply1 0`, there will be a type error saying that there is still not enough information to resolve the overloading. We have to explicitly specify the result type to be `Int` in this case to get through.

However, in `Twice2`, the instance is for any function type. GHC will immediately resolve it (GHC never backtracks, so if an instance clearly matches, it's always chosen), and then try to establish the preconditions: in this case, the equality constraint, which then forces the result type to be `Int` and allows us to resolve the `Example` constraint, too. We can say `apply2 0` without further type annotations.

So this is a rather subtle point about GHC's instance resolution, and the equality constraint here helps GHC's type checker along in a way that requires fewer type annotations by the user.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it something like that, but your simplified example made things much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

to complete the @kosmikus answer

same applies to purescript - you need equality constraint to derive type properly (you can try here http://try.purescript.org)

```
module Main where

import Prelude

-- copied from https://github.com/purescript/purescript-type-equality/blob/master/src/Type/Equality.purs
class TypeEquals a b | a -> b, b -> a where
  to :: a -> b
  from :: b -> a

instance refl :: TypeEquals a a where
  to a = a
  from a = a

-----------------

class Twice1 f where
  twice1 :: f -> f

class Twice2 f where
  twice2 :: f -> f

instance mytwice1 :: Twice1 (a -> a) where
  twice1 f = f >>> f

instance mytwice2 :: TypeEquals a b => Twice2 (a -> b) where
  twice2 f = f >>> from >>> f

class Example a where
  transform :: Int -> a

instance exampleInt :: Example Int where
  transform n = n + 1

instance exampleChar :: Example Char where
  transform _ = 'x'

{--
-- will raise error
--   No type class instance was found for Main.Twice1 (Int -> t1)

apply1 x = twice1 transform x

-- to resolve error add type declaration
apply1 :: Int -> Int

--}

-- compiles without error and manual type declaration, has type Int -> Int automatically
apply2 x = twice2 transform x
```

---

But in idris you don't

```
module Main

import Prelude

interface Twice f where
  twice : f -> f

Twice (a -> a) where
  twice f = f . f

interface Example a where
  transform : Int -> a

Example Int where
  transform n = n + 1

Example Char where
  transform _ = 'x'

-- run in REPL to see that it derives properly:

-- $ idris src/15_EqualityConstraint_Twice_class.idr
-- *src/15_EqualityConstraint_Twice_class> :t twice transform
-- twice transform : Int -> Int

-- Summary:
-- in idris you dont need equality constaint to derive type of such functions properly
```