# Type unification with multi-parameter type classes

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
class Coerce a b where coerce :: a -> b
instance Coerce a a where coerce a = a
```

Now, this won't work: `coerce 0 :: Int`
But if the instance is replace with this, the expression works:

```
instance a ~ b => Coerce a b where coerce x = x
```

Why?

Comment: This question is somewhat similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553705/haskell-equality-constraint-in-instance/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Equality constraint in instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553705/haskell-equality-constraint-in-instance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can tell you why the first one *doesn't* work.

`Coerce` could potentially be defined for any possible *pair* of types. `coerce 0 :: Int` is parsed as `(coerce 0) :: Int`. So you've fixed the `b` in `coerce :: a -> b` with the type annotation, but not the the `a`.

Numeric literals are polymorphic, so `0` has type `Num a => a`. That won't work; there's no instance matching `Coerce a Int`. There could be `Coerce Double Int`, `Coerce Complex Int`, etc, so knowing that `b` is `Int` isn't enough to infer that that `0` is an `Int`. We'd need to say `coerce (0 :: Int) :: Int` to fix both type parameters.

I *believe* the second one works because constraints on the instance declaration aren't used to help resolve type classes. `instance a ~ b => Coerce a b` is matched exactly as if you'd written `instance Coerce a b`. I.e. this is the most general instance possible (for the purpose of type class resolution), which well match any possible call to `coerce` (and so you can't write any other non-overlapping instances). The `a ~ b` constraint is only applied *after* the instance is chosen.

Since you have one instance that matches anything, there's no problem selecting an instance for `coerce 0 :: Int`, even though we still have the same problem of not knowing what type the `0` is. But then after instance selection, we now have the additional constraint `a ~ Int`, which allows unambiguous types to be assigned to everything.

Comment: However, although the `instance a ~ b => Coerce a b` works *alone*, it is also going to overlap with every other possible instance you want to write, making the class as a whole useless.