# Haskell instance constraint (JSTypeString ~ jstype) =>

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I was reading some blog post related to Yesod (http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/04/client-side) from 2012 when a wild instance declaration with constraint appeared I don't even know how to name.

```
instance (JSTypeString ~ jstype) => IsString (JSValue jstype) where
```

Can anybody tell me what exactly the tilde does in constraint place? I guessed it means something like `jstype` must be of type `JSTypeString` but I'm not sure. A name for this would be nice to know, too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called "equality constraint".

Comment: And the reason it is used here instead of simply `instance IsString (JSValue JSTypeString)` is probably related to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553705/haskell-equality-constraint-in-instance - though I can't claim to really understand it.

Comment: The instance `IsString (JSValue JSTypeString)` will only ever be selected if the type is known to be precisely `JSValue JSTypeString`. If it is `JSValue x` for some type variable `x`, then this instance will not be selected. However, the `(JSTypeString ~ jstype) => IsString (JSValue jstype)` instance will be selected for `JSValue x` for any x, *after* which the compiler will throw an error if `x` is not `JSTypeString`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Ah yes it's a duplicate. I just couldn't find anything on Google to get a grip of it's name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for explanation. I was looking for this feature for some time now and stumbled upon it by accident. Thanks for explanation. :)