# Equality constraints in type instances

Tags: haskell, type-families

Let's say I have the following:

```
type family TF a b
```

Can I write something like this

```
type instance TF Int t = (t ~ (x,y)) => (Int,x,y)
```

as a perhaps silly example.

This question is along the same theme as the accepted answer to this question: [Haskell: Equality constraint in instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553705/haskell-equality-constraint-in-instance)

I want to match the type instance even if I'm not sure the second argument is a pair then force the second argument to be a pair (with a resulting compile error if this is not successful).

Comment: I'd guess not, since `x,y` are not in scope. As written, that would essentially involve existential types, which are not "first-class" in Haskell.

Comment: `type family Fst x where Fst (x,y) = x; type family Snd x where Snd (x,y) = y; type instance TF Int t = (Int, Fst t, Snd t)`. The simpler thing to do is to give your index a single, closed family which only reduces for pairs: `type instance TF Int x = TF_Int x; type family TF_Int x where TF_Int (x,y) = (Int, x, y)`.

Comment: @user2407038, I believe the `Fst`/`Snd` approach is "lazier", and will therefore allow more useful reductions.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to do this in GHC 8.0 using the new [TypeError](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1-rc1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#custom-compile-time-errors) feature, depending on what you mean by "force the second argument to be a pair".

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Pair where

import GHC.TypeLits

type family Fst p where
  Fst (x, y) = x
  Fst _t = TypeError (Text "Fst: expected a pair, but got " :<>: ShowType _t)

type family Snd p where
  Snd (x, y) = y
  Snd _t = TypeError (Text "Snd: expected a pair, but got " :<>: ShowType _t)

type family TF a b
type instance TF Int t = (Int, Fst t, Snd t)
```

Now you should get a compile error if you try to apply `TF Int` to a non-tuple:

```
*Pair> let x = x in x :: TF Int Bool

<interactive>:9:1: error:
    • Fst: expected a pair, but got Bool
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: (Int, (TypeError ...), (TypeError ...))
```

However, this doesn't really "force" the argument to be a pair any more than calling `fromJust` "forces" its argument to be of the form `Just x`. It is really programming with partial functions at the type level.

Well-formedness of type family applications is totally determined by the kind of the type family, and a pair `(x, y)` has the same kind `*` as, say, `Bool` does. You can't magically incur a constraint simply by writing down an application of a type family. If you want to get a constraint at the type level, you have to write it to the left side of `=>`.

In the linked question, `CanFilter (b -> c) a` is already a constraint, so it can imply `b ~ c`.

Comment: "It is really programming with partial functions at the type level." I don't think this is exactly true here - it would be more true without the `TypeError` case. In that case, you get `TF Int Bool ~ (Int, Fst Bool, Snd Bool)` - the last two types are "stuck" (i.e. they can *never* be reduced) but they do not produce a type error. But `Fst Bool` is still inhabited by bottom! The point of `TypeError` is so if it *ever* appears in a type, it is really a type error. `Fst Bool` *with* the TypeError is *not* inhabited by bottom - because the type itself simply does not exist.

Comment: I don't follow. If I don't have a `TypeError` case, then `Fst` is total; `Fst Int` is a stuck type like you say. The purpose of `TypeError` is to make `Fst Int` an error, so `Fst` becomes partial.